# Como atualizar somente uma coluna do registro?

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, formulário, sql-update

Eu fiz um codigo pra atualizar algumas colunas do meu registro quando preciso. Tem 7 colunas listadas no `array`, mas geralmente eu so vou atualizar 1 ou 2 colunas. Com esse codigo eu consigo atualizar meu registro, mas eu tenho que colocar dados em todos os `inputs`, no caso eu n poderia escrever algo no `input name="keywords"` e clicar em `SUBMIT` e deixar os outros `inputs` em branco, pq se eu fizer isso só vai atualizar a coluna `keywords` e deixar o resto das colunas em branco.

Então eu queria saber: Como atualizo uma coluna sem afetar as outras?

```
if(isset($_POST["updateBTN"])){    
  $insert_data = array(

    ':title'            => $_POST['title'],
    ':keywords'         => $_POST['keywords'],
    ':img'              => $_POST['img'],
    ':widht'            => $_POST['widht'],
    ':status'           => $_POST['status'],
    ':name'             => $_POST['name'],
    ':height'           => $_POST['height']

  );

$query = "UPDATE table SET keywords = :keywords, img = :img, widht = :widht, status = :status, name = :name, height = :height WHERE title = :title";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($insert_data);

}
```

html:

```
<form  method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="title"> 
    <span data-placeholder="Title"></span>          
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="keywords"> 
    <span data-placeholder="keywords"></span>          
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="img"> 
    <span data-placeholder="img"></span>          
</div>
.
.
.
<button type="submit" name="updateBTN">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Achei um jeito, não sei se é o melhor jeito mas é um jeito que comigo rodou redondo!!! :-)

Comment: DEIXE-ME ETENDER AMIGO, VOCÊ QUER ATUALIZAR SOMENTE A COLUNA QUE FOI ESCRITA. é isso ? Sem ter que preencher tudo. apenas por preencher?

Comment: @RiscadoOoOoOeRabisCadoO Sim

Comment: O LEO JA RESPONDEU AMIGO. COPIE O CODIGO DELE Q DA CERTO!

Comment: Se achar interessante com `jquery` posso postar na resposta. http://kithomepage.com/sos/foreach-colunas-valores-para-insert-jquery.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tem que montar a query de acordo com os valores não nulos do array, veja como:

Comentários no próprio código.

```
if(isset($_POST["updateBTN"])){

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NOME_DB', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA', array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));

    $sets="";
    $title="";
    $keywords="";
    $img="";
    $widht="";
    $status="";
    $name="";
    $height="";

      $update = array(
        'title'            => $_POST['title'],
        'keywords'         => $_POST['keywords'],
        'img'              => $_POST['img'],
        'widht'            => $_POST['widht'],
        'status'           => $_POST['status'],
        'name'             => $_POST['name'],
        'height'           => $_POST['height']
      );

        //percorre o array
        foreach ($update as $column => $value) {

            //verifica se não há valores nulos
            if ($value!=""){
                //constroi a variável para usar na declaração UPDATE
                $sets .= $column." = :".$column.", ";

                /**********************************************
                    no caso dos names dos inputs iguais
                    aos nomes das colunas da tabela do banco
                    cria as variáveis com os names dos inputs
                ***********************************************/
                $$column=$value;

            }
        }

         //retira a ultima virgula
         $sets = rtrim($sets, ', ');

         //monta a query 
         $query = "UPDATE nomeTabela SET $sets WHERE title = :title";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindValue(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($keywords!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":keywords", $keywords, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }   
    if ($img!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":img", $img, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if ($widht!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":widht", $widht, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if ($status!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if ($name!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if ($height!=""){
        $statement->bindValue(":height", $height, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $statement->execute(); 

}
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: sets` está apontando para `$sets` que está dentro do `if`. Será q vc esqueceu algo?

Answer (score 0):

De uma maneira bem simples você pode ir checando sua variáveis e concatenando na sua instrução SQL caso não estiver vazia.

**Exemplo:**

```
$query = "UPDATE TABELA SET ". (empty($variavel) ? "" : "CAMPO = $variavel") ." WHERE TITLEID = $TITLE";
```

Espero que ajude.